# XSD definition for simpleType + restriction + anyAttribute

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a simple schema definition for a simple type:

```
<xs:simpleType name="std_types-bit-type">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
     <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
     <xs:maxInclusive value="1"/>
   </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Elsewhere there's:

```
<xs:element name="comp" type="std_types-bit-type"/>
```

One can then create XML elements like this:

```
<comp>1</comp>
```

I'd like to allow the document creators to add arbitrary (to me, but meaningful to them) attributes, such as:

```
<comp index="2">1</comp>
```

Since I can't know all the possible attributes in advance, `xs:anyAttribute` is intended for just this situation. And in fact, defining this for complexTypes is straightforward. The problem is that I haven't been able to find the magic combination of schema elements that lets me associate `xs:anyAttribute` with a simpleType/simpleContent restriction.

I can't imagine that this is not possible, but it's beating me so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Attributes may be added when a type is derived by extension; facets can be added a type is derived by restriction.  *So, allow yourself two definitions*...**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:simpleType name="std_types-bit-base-type">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
      <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
      <xs:maxInclusive value="1"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:complexType name="std_types-bit-type">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="std_types-bit-base-type">
        <xs:anyAttribute/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of this. One simple element definition to two. And since the schema is tool-generated (and I'm writing the tool) that means more complexity. xs:anyAttribute also has to be present in both the extension and restriction (or xmllint barks).

Comment: I rolled back my edit because I had slightly misread your answer. My stab at a solution involved extending xs:int (adding xs:anyAttribute) into a complexType, then restricting that. xs:attribute is valid within an xs:restriction within an xs:simpleContent within an xs:complexType. Rereading your answer, this time I saw you first restricted the basic type, then extended it with xs:anyAttribute. That's obviously a much cleaner approach. Sorry for the error...